# How to get info from Users model into a controller other than UsersController

Tags: cakephp

I need to pull info from the Users model into my BookmarkController. In the UsersController I can do something like $user = $this->Users->get, as the UsersController is aware of the Users model. How to do this in the BookmarkController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
$this->Bookmarks->Users->get(...  // if they're associated models
```

Or:

```
$this->loadModel('Users');
$this->Users->get(...  // if they're not associated models
```

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed with no associated model.